# Spring Data mongodb like query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, repository, spring-data-mongodb

I want to make a text search case insensitive with regex query with spring-data mongo .

For example in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%';
```

How can i make this query with spring-data mongo using MongoRepository Query DSL ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is the raw mongo query for your sql :

`db.Customers.find( { CustomerName: /^a/ } )`

**or**

`db.Customers.find( { CustomerName: { $regex: /^a/ } } )`

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

@Query("{$or : [{'name': { $regex: ?0, $options:'i' }}, {'description': { $regex: ?0, $options:'i' }}]}")
List<Product> findProductByRegexString(final String regexString);
```

you can use query like that hope help you